# not understanding a call in django

Tags: python, django, sockets, websocket, socket.io

```
from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace

class ChatNamespace(BaseNamespace):
        _registry = {} 
       def initialize(self):
           self._registry[id(self)] = self
```

I am looking at this code and not understanding [id(self)] why ID has been called and how it's effecting the current line of code?

Answer (score 0):

_registry is a dictionary, and specifically, it is a class-level object (meaning that every instance of this class shares the same dictionary.  id is a built in python method (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) which returns the “identity” of an object and is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. (For CPython, this is the memory address of the object.).  In other words, what this is doing is adding a new registry entry with the key being a "globally" unique value for this object and the value being the object.

Comment: Ah okay, is this not why we have indexes!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?  Some of this depends on what the rest of the code does... if you mean array indexes in the sense of why didn't they just make _registry a list and append self to this list, it would depend on what they want to do with the code ... it very well could be overengineered